# Set up communication logstash with SSL using http input plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

**Mine question:**

- How sent logs to logstash (using for example postman) with SSL? Should I include some certificate in request Header or what?

**Additional questions:**

- How to set up http logstash input with SSL? I already does it right?
- How communication with logstash throught SSL works?

**What I already have:**

- Working **ELK docker image** based on: https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk
- Working **logstash-input-http-plugin** based on: https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-input-http-plugin
- My logstash.conf file looks like:

> ```
> input {
>   http {
>         port => "5000"
>   }
>   http {
>         port => "5001"
>         ssl => on
>         keystore => "KeyStore.jks"
>         keystore_password => "1qaz@WSX"
>   }
> }
>
> output {
>   elasticsearch {
>       hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
>   }
> }
> ```

- **KeyStore.jks** file is created using section 1 of : https://support.globalsign.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2121490-java-keytool---create-keystore
- I copy my **KeyStore.jks** to **docker-image** and logstash http plugin see this file

**Workflow:**

1. First component sent logs to first input using postman and it work fine - Response: "OK"
2. When second component try send logs to second input: have no response (and no logs about receive request in docker-compose logs) - in postman: "Could not get any response"

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: I refactor my question. It looks like I need some certificate somewhere I guess. I have logstash logs that first input receive request but have no logs about SSL input.

Answer (score 1):

```
input {
http { port => "5000"
  }
http {
    port => "5001"
```

> ssl => on   =>     change this from on to true

```
keystore => "KeyStore.jks"
keystore_password => "1qaz@WSX"
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
  hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
 }
}
```

This is because ***ssl accepts boolean value(true or false)***. this will solve your issue , and it will work if you have correctly created your .**jks** file.